# Java entity modeling with table that relates to several others

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have a doubt about how the modeling of my entity would be. Come on, I have a table in the database that serves to save documents from my system, this table has the columns id, fk_id (element foreign key), fk_table (entity name) and file_name (stores the name of my file) .

I did a lot of research before posting my question here, but I didn't find anything related to it, what would my entities, user, patient and doctor?

DB:

| id | fk_id | fk_table | file_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | user | test1.jpg |
| 2 | 32 | doctor | test2.pdf |
| 3 | 61 | user | test10.pdf |
| 4 | 100 | patient | test5.jpg |

Class:

```
public class User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String LastName;
// What would a one-to-many relationship look like?
}
public class patient{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
// What would a one-to-many relationship look like?
}
```

Comment: I think the modeling of your database is a bit unusual. First of all you cannot check referential integrity with a foreign key constraint. You also don't have a pure relationship between this table and the other tables. Why don't you save the file_name directly on the tables user, doctor and patient?

Comment: Hi, @SimonMArtinelli. This is an existing database. The relationship in this table is many to one, so a user can have multiple documents registered in this table.

Comment: Ah now I understand because you asked about many-to-one but it's one-to-many

Comment: Sorry, that's right. one to many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Where`. But be aware that `@Where` is a Hibernate annotation. It's not in the JPA standard.

For example in the User entity: (I assume that your table is mapped to an entity called Document)

```
@Where( clause = "fk_table = 'user'")
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_id")
@OneToMany
private List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>( );
```

Comment: I'm starting in spring, I have another question, will I create a repository for the internal one or for the document entity to return the data?

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood what you went through, applied it to my case and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based only on standard JPA annotations. The idea is to create an inheritance hierarchy for the documents table. The base is:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "XX_DOCUMENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "fk_table")
public abstract class BaseDocument {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;
}
```

Here we define that all entities extending this will go to the same table, with the `fk_table` column to discriminate. The entities extending it are defined as follows:

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("doctor")
public class DoctorDocument extends BaseDocument {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id")
    private Doctor doctor;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("patient")
public class PatientDocument extends BaseDocument {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id")
    private Patient patient;
}

// and so on
```

The interesting thing is that we are reusing the column `fk_id` to point to the right table. From a small experiment, Hibernate seems to not have problems with it. I would suggest that you manage the DB creation another way just to be safe.

The `Doctor`, `Patient` etc need not have a common base class, e.g.:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "XX_DOCTOR")
public class Doctor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
    private Collection<DoctorDocument> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    // any doctor-specific fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "XX_PATIENT")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Collection<PatientDocument> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    // any patient-specific fields
}

// and so on
```

You can read a (doctor, patient, ...)'s documents from the relevant collection. You can even query `BaseDocument` instances based on any criteria.

You can even go ahead and do more fabcy stuff with the Java code. E.g. define an interface `HasDocuments`:

```java
public interface HasDocuments<D extends BaseDocument> {
    Collection<D> getDocuments();
}
```

`Doctor`, `Patient`, ..., implements this, so they can all be treated the same way.